# Passing results out of NodeJS database function to use outside of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sqlite3

I have the following code I am using with a SQLite3 npm module.

```js
db.all("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '3', function(err, rows) {
   return rows
})
```

I would like to access the data from `rows` outside of this code, for example...

```js
db.all("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '3', function(err, rows) {
   return rows
}) 

// >>> *** I want to call the results for rows here ***
```

Could someone explain with a quick example how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a use of promises, for example:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  db.all("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '3', function(err, rows) {
    // Check if there's an error, if it exists the promise will end up.
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
      return
    }

    resolve(rows)
  })
}).then(function (rows) {
  // You can make use of your code here
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Promises act asynchronously so it will be `resolved` once the data is readed from your db.

You go [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) to learn a little bit more. The documentation is awesome.

Comment: Thank you just what I am looking for... :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access rows from outside the callback, because is asynchronous, the callback is telling you when you can actually use it.

However, you could use `async / await` if you are not keen on nested callbacks:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const dbAllAsync = promisify(db.all);

(async function() {
    const rows = await dbAllAsync("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '3'");
    console.log(rows); // you can use rows here
})();
```

**Caveat**:

Check if your version of node supports `promisify`. If it doesn't use a library such as bluebird. Same applies for `async / await`, in this case you could use a transpiler such as babel, or just upgrade node :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)